# Wordpress meta in permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type called `patch`. Every patch have a meta key `version` and the value of this meta is always unique. For example:

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.1
- 1.5
- ...

I want to make special permalink structure so every patch could be accessible by this URL structure:

`www.site.ru/patch/%version%`

So `www.site.ru/patch/1.0.1` would lead to specific patch post witch meta key `version` value equals `1.0.1`.

How can I do so?

I guess there should be a way to somehow automaticlly transform `%version%` to a structure like `index.php?p=*needed_patch_post_id*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
add_action('init', 'rb_add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'rb_create_permalinks', 10, 3);

function rb_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%version%', '([^/]+)', 'version=');   
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('patch', 'patch/%version%/', false);
}

function rb_create_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

    $no_data = 'no-speciality';

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if($post->post_type != 'patch' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))

    return $permalink;

    $var1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'version', true);

    $var1 = sanitize_title($var1);

    if(!$var1) { $var1 = $no_data; }

    $permalink = str_replace('%version%', $var1, $permalink);

    return $permalink;
}
```

I hope this will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I am redirected on site main page when clicking on patch links :(